# How to allow logged out users to upload media?

Tags: uploads, users, media, library

How do i allow non logged in users access to the media library for uploads? I am making an anonymous blog, i got posting with images to work, but i need the media button above the editor to work so people can upload documents, mp3 and html5 video.

I am also using to comment attachment plugin but it doesnt allow non logged in users to upload attachments.

How can i make this happen?

The last resort i will hack the core if needed but i would like to not do that so i can update.